# Online resources for German verbs classes: strong, weak, mixed.

Tags: resource, verb

I've been searching for a nice complete list showing all the different verb classes (strong, weak, mixed) but couldn't find anything.

Can someone point me to a good online resource?

They should be divided by class and if possible with indications about exceptions. Bonus points if other "features" are included (such as conjugation, etc.).

It doesn't matter how they are listed, as long as I can understand which class they belong to.

Comment: I've found this too, although the verb class is not specified: [Deutsche Verben](http://www.vocabulix.com/konjugation/Deutsche-Verben.html)

Comment: The list "Deutsche Verben"  is extremely silly. It contains regular verbs and it contains  irregular verbs with prefixes. This way you would get a list with thousands of verbs. But we have only  about 100 irregular verbs as in English.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wiktionary has dedicated categories:

- [German verbs](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category%3aGerman_verbs)

  - [German strong verbs](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category%3aGerman_strong_verbs)

    - [German class 1 strong verbs](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category%3aGerman_class_1_strong_verbs)
    - [German class 2 strong verbs](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category%3aGerman_class_2_strong_verbs)
    - [German class 3 strong verbs](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category%3aGerman_class_3_strong_verbs)
    - [German class 4 strong verbs](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category%3aGerman_class_4_strong_verbs)
    - [German class 5 strong verbs](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category%3aGerman_class_5_strong_verbs)
    - [German class 6 strong verbs](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category%3aGerman_class_6_strong_verbs)
    - [German class 7 strong verbs](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category%3aGerman_class_7_strong_verbs)
  - [German weak verbs](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category%3aGerman_weak_verbs)
  - etc.

Comment: One thing I noticed: If I click the first "German class 1 strong verbs" it points me to weak verbs?

Comment: I don't think that a learner of German learns irregular verbs with seven  lists. Furthermore the lists contains irregular verbs with prefixes. Nonsense. If a verb is irregular  as bieten/bot/geboten  the compounds with prefixes as an/auf/ver- have the same forms.

Answer (score 4):

I found [Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/) a valuable resource for German grammar. For example, see [Flexionsklassen](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-V/Texte/Flexionsklassen.html?MenuId=Word2111) for strong/weak verbs.

Comment: I find the list "unregelmäßige Verben" of canoo.net not useful for learners. A learner needs one alphabetical list and not 7 seven where he needs half an hour till he finds the verb he needs.

Answer (score 1):

Strong or irregular verbs are verbs that form the stem forms by vowel change as fliegen flog geflogen. The verbs that are the most frequently used are irregular. In lists of dictionaries there are about a hundred.

Weak or regular verbs are verbs of the type machen machte gemacht. Most verbs are regular.

There is a mixed type with endings and vowel change as bringen brachte gebracht. About a handful. They are of course irregular, too.

What you really need is a list of irregular verbs. It is easy to see whether it is type 1 or the mixed type.

I've just had a look at some lists of irregular verbs (IV)  online. It is easy to see that those who made those lists never learnt from such lists as a learner would. For learning purposes these lists a worthless.

What a learner needs are three forms as

- fliegen flog *geflogen ( perfect with sein, verb of movement)
- reiten ritt *geritten
- sprechen* sprach gesprochen ( present tense with vowel change).
- bringen brachte gebracht

The subjunctive forms should be added in a list "IV with subjunctive"

- kommen kam *gekommen - (subjunctive:) er komme, er käme.

You see there is still a lot to learn for people who write grammars and make lists.

Almost all lists of IV are edited negligently. You never see an introduction to these lists which would inform a learner what he or she has to know about IV.

Comment: maybe this list is more suited? https://www.lsa.umich.edu/german/hmr/Grammatik/Verb_Summaries/Strong_Weak_Mixed.html